# How to declare variable with a lot of new lines in Rail's haml file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, newline, haml

### version

Rails 6.0.3
ruby 2.7.2

### What I want to do

There is text_area_tag in haml file

```
text_area_tag("context[]",nil,:wrap=>"virtual",:rows=>"8")
```

Now I wanna add like this sentence as placeholder

```
placeholder test

Hi I'm Mike, placeholder
new line

new line
new line

Hi I'm Michelle
new line
new line

Hi I'm Goku
new line new line

(and more... and more...)
・
・
・
```

### Problem

I could declare variable in view haml file like

```
- var = "placeholder test &#13;&#10; Hi I'm Mike, placeholder &#13;&#10; new line &#13;&#10; &#13;&#10; new line .........."
```

but it's too long, super spaghetti code.
If I could use like javascript↓, It would be useful

```
const var = `
placeholder test

Hi I'm Mike, placeholder
new line

......
`
```

If somebody knows better way to declare variable with a lot of new line in haml file, let me know please.

Answer (score 1):

To create new line, you can use "\n" direct on haml file, or use a variable like `times4` in my way, and note not set the name to `4times`, it will not working!

```
%h4 Content
- var = "placeholder test &#13;&#10; Hi I'm Mike, placeholder &#13;&#10; new line &#13;&#10; &#13;&#10; new line .........."
- iso1 = "placeholder test \nHi I'm Mike, placeholder \nnew line \n \nnew line .........."
- times4 = "\n" * 4
- iso2 = "placeholder test \nHi I'm Mike, placeholder \nnew line #{times4}new line .........."
= text_area_tag("context[]",nil,:wrap=>"virtual",:rows=>"8", :placeholder=>"#{iso2}")
```

Happy coding!

Update for multi lines, you can use "|" in variable declaration, example:

```
- iso3 = "placeholder test \n" + |
"Hi I'm Mike, placeholder \n" + |
"new line #{times4}" + |
"new line .........." |
```

Note it ends with a "|", if not, you will get a error!

Do the more, door the move! : D

Comment: thanks for giving me "4times" way :)   But unfortunately it needs long one line sentence in variable at least right?  maybe I will do that

Comment: Updated for multi lines of var declaration!